# In N-Tier Architecture Which Layer Asks A Security Layer To Authenticate A Login

Tags: winforms, security, n-tier-architecture

I am putting together a WinForms application which I would like to be based on an N-Tier design. For now I have 4 layers which are as follows:

- Presentation
- Business
- Data Access
- Security

My question comes from using the first window which is the login window which asks for a user account and password.  Once the button at login has been pressed should the Presentation Layer ask the Security Layer to authenticate or should the Presentation Layer Ask the Business Layer which in turn asks the Security Layer? I ask this because it appears so far that all Presentation actions interact with the Business Layer.

I put the security actions in a separate layer because I want that layer to be usable by other projects. It will address authentication by using Active Directory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The definition of your authentication rules are a business concern. That should be in the business layer. How you implement and execute them is something else. If that is a reusable component, then a separate layer is fine, but it is an implementation detail.

Comment: This is a somewhat confusing topic when I see articles like following: http://dotnetdaily.net/tutorials/n-tier-architecture-asp-net/
 It shows security outside of the business layer.  What it does not answer and what I was asking is what layer would talk to the security layer to get the authorization carried out.  Sounds like from what you said that the Presentation layer will get the user input and pass it to the business layer which will in turn gets the security layer to carry out the needed task.